# How to run "rm -rf !(folder)" in dash

Tags: shell, bamboo, dash-shell

I've written a deployment plan in Bamboo, which runs all the scripts on an agent using sh, and since those agents run ubuntu 14.04 that equates to dash.

I want to do the following step:

```
rm -rf !(${bamboo.scripts_folder})
```

This should remove all the files/folders except the ones in the variable.

This works fine in bash, but when i run this in dash it gives me:

```
dash: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I tried running the following at the start of the script to force it to run as bash instead:

```
if [ "$(ps -p "$$" -o comm=)" != "bash" ]; then
    bash "$0" "$@"
    exit "$?"
fi
```

While that seems to have worked for me in the past, in this case for some reason, it doesn't appear to, as I get:

```
line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I tried updating my script to read:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Early $0"
if [ "$(ps -p "$$" -o comm=)" != "bash" ]; then
    bash "$0" "$@"
    exit "$?"
fi

echo "Later $0"

rm -rf !(${bamboo.scripts_folder})
```

I was hoping that the echo statements would print out the shell that was currently running, but instead I get:

```
11-Apr-2017 13:51:25    Early /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp/49020935-118947854-118064182-ScriptBuildTask-740980554529016045.sh
11-Apr-2017 13:51:25    Early /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp/49020935-118947854-118064182-ScriptBuildTask-740980554529016045.sh
11-Apr-2017 13:51:25    Later /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp/49020935-118947854-118064182-ScriptBuildTask-740980554529016045.sh
11-Apr-2017 13:51:25    /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp/49020935-118947854-118064182-ScriptBuildTask-740980554529016045.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
11-Apr-2017 13:51:25    /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp/49020935-118947854-118064182-ScriptBuildTask-740980554529016045.sh: line 13: `rm -rf !(font)'
```

This didn't give me anything more to go on. Can anyone suggest the "right" way to run this using dash? Or the "right" way to make this execute using bash instead of dash (note that bamboo launches everything as sh and you can't change that)

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/Making-a-Bamboo-Script-execute-using-bin-bash/qaq-p/205364

Comment: That's in my question, it doesn't work

Comment: Extglobs are very much a bash-only feature. Part of something being a bash-only feature is that it... well... *doesn't exist* in shells that aren't bash (or similarly extended).

Comment: BTW, `${bamboo.scripts_folder}` isn't a valid shell variable name. Is that being replaced with a value by something else (ie. code in a different language running a template to generate your script)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a way? Yes.

Will you like it? Probably not.

```
set --; for d in */; do [ "$d" = "ignoreme/" ] && continue; set -- "$@" "$d"; done
rm -rf "$@"
```

---

That said, your other script isn't using dash at all -- at least, if it's called in accordance with its shebang. In that context, it just needs `shopt -s extglob` passed to enable extglobs, which are an extension that's turned off by default:

```
#!/bin/bash

# you almost certainly don't need this at all
[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || [ -n "$ran_reexec" ] || ran_reexec=1 exec bash "$0" "$@"

shopt -s extglob    
rm -rf !(ignoreme)
```

Comment: It's run with dash, as bamboo runs everything with sh, and in ubuntu sh is a symlink to dash...

Comment: Just because it runs everything with sh doesn't mean everything that sh runs *also* uses sh. `sh -c yourcommand` will honor `#!/bin/bash` if that's what `yourcommand` starts with (and it's marked executable). Not true for `sh yourcommand`, of course, but that falls into the category of "don't do that" -- using `sh yourcommand` means your tool can't run `yourcommand` if it's a compiled binary, a Python script, or otherwise *anything* but a POSIX-compliant script.

Answer (score 0):

I know I can do:

```
find . ! -name 'folder' -delete -maxdepth 1
```

Is there a way without find?